# fill a select element in order of other select changed event - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two select element, 
the first is list of country that when we
selected one of the option, the second select element member fill from DB
 this list is province of selected country now when we select related
 province from DB how can I add option to second select by angularJs

```
<div class=" col-md-6 col-xs-12" ng-controller="CountryController " ng-init="GetList()" ng-class="{'has-error':regForm.CountyId.$error.invalidSelectValue}">
   <span class="iconHolder fa fa-flag-checkered"></span>
   <select material-select watch ng-model="Countries" name="CountyId" data-val-required="مشخص کردن کشور الزامی است ." required show-message ng-change="GetProvinceList(Countries,regForm.province)">
      <option value="">country</option>
      <option ng-repeat="country in CountryList" value="{{country.Id}}">{{country.Name}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class=" col-md-6 col-xs-12" ng-controller="CountryController" ng-init="GetProvinceList(null,regForm.province)">
   <span class="iconHolder fa fa-flag-checkered"></span>                        @*ng-options="record.Id as record.Name for record in GetProvinceList()"*@
   <select ng-model="province"  name="province" SelectFill>
      <option value="">province</option>
      <option ng-repeat="province in ProvinceList" value="{{province.Id}}">{{province.Name}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

and this is my control:

```
var CountryController = function ($scope, $location, GetCountriesFactory, ProvinceFactory) {
    $scope.CountryList = [];
    $scope.ProvinceList = [];
    $scope.GetList = function () {
        GetCountriesFactory.GetList().then(function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                $scope.CountryList = response.List;
            }
        })
    }
    $scope.GetProvinceList = function (countryId, _element) {
        console.log(angular.element(_element));
        angular.element(_element).removeAttr('disabled')
        $scope.ProvinceList = [{ Id: 5555, Name: 'hamid' }];
        return $scope.ProvinceList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="AjaxCtrl">
      <h1>AJAX - Oriented</h1>
    <div>
        Country: 
        <select id="country" ng-model="country" ng-options="country for country in countries">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        City: <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in cities"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        Suburb: <select id="suburb" ng-disabled="!suburbs" ng-model="suburb" ng-options="suburb for suburb in suburbs"><option value=''>Select</option></select>        
    </div>
</div>
  <div ng-controller="StaticCtrl">
      <h1>Static - Oriented</h1>
      <p>This approach may be better when you have the entire dataset</p>
    <div>
        Country: 
        <select id="country" ng-model="cities" ng-options="country for (country, cities) in countries">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        City: <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="suburbs" ng-options="city for (city, suburbs) in cities"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        Suburb: <select id="suburb" ng-disabled="!suburbs" ng-model="suburb" ng-options="suburb for suburb in suburbs"><option value=''>Select</option></select>        
    </div>
  </div>
```

> And in control :

```
function AjaxCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.countries = ['usa', 'canada', 'mexico', 'france'];
    $scope.$watch('country', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) $scope.cities = ['Los Angeles', 'San Francisco'];
    });
    $scope.$watch('city', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) $scope.suburbs = ['SOMA', 'Richmond', 'Sunset'];
    });
}
```